# Angularfire undefined variable

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

Im try to get my current user storage on the realtime database from firebase using angularfire2

```
  public user: any;
  public userRef: any
  public currentUser: any;
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private userProvider: UserProvider,
    private fireDateBase: AngularFireDatabase
  ) {
    this.currentUser = this.fireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
    this.userRef = this.fireDateBase.object('CITYNAV_USERS/' + this.currentUser);
    this.getCurrentUser();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
  }

  public getCurrentUser(): void {
    this.userRef.snapshotChanges().subscribe(action => {
      this.user = action.payload.val();
      console.log(this.user);
    });
  }
```

but for some reason when the `this.user` tell that is undefined and i have no idea why. Any idea.

**HTML**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div class="wrapper-profile">
    <img src="assets/imgs/logo-f.png" alt="">
    <div class="wrapper-avatar">
      <div class="avatar">
        <img src="{{user.avatar}}" alt="avatar">
      </div>
      <button ion-button color="icons-color" clear>Cambiar imagen</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-profile-form">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>
        <ion-icon name="ios-person-outline"></ion-icon> Nombre</ion-label>
      <ion-input clearInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.name"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>
        <ion-icon name="ios-mail-outline"></ion-icon> Email</ion-label>
      <ion-input clearInput type="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>
        <ion-icon name="ios-lock-outline"></ion-icon> Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input clearInput type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div class="profile-btn">
      <button class="btn-edit" ion-button color="secondary" round>Editar informacion</button>
      <button class="btn-logout" ion-button color="secondary" (click)="logOut()" round>Log Oout</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Here is the html to render the user object after get it from the realtime database.

**console log the response object**

```
    Object { 
      avatar: "assets/imgs/avatar.jpg", 
      created: "Wed Nov 08 2017 16:54:53 GMT+0100", 
      email: "mianfrigo@gmail.com", 
      password: "Atenas10", 
      rol: "user", 
      userName: "Miguel Frias" 
    }
```

Comment: No body have some idea what could be wrong...?

Comment: How does your incoming data look like? Is the data there if you console log it inside subscribe like suggested in answer?

Comment: yes i console log the data inside of the subscribe and the data is there.

Comment: and how does it look like? Copy paste the JSON format into your question please.

Comment: That is the console log object that i get from the response, but what is weird is that i get undefined from the console and i dont know why because i assign the response to the `this.user` that is a public variable. so im really lost there.

Comment: Which is it? You say you get the object when you console log but then when you console log user is undefined? So where does it show the object in console log?

Comment: No  the problem is when i try render the user object on the HTML after assign it to `this.user` to then display the information of the user, give me the error that the user is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now when you have made the appropriate changes to place your console log inside the callback (`subscribe`)...

You can initialize your `user` or use `*ngIf` in your template, as the data is coming async, view is rendered before data has arrived. Or you can use the safe navigation operator, safe navigation operator does not work with two-way-binding though, so you'd need to split that to one-way-binding and `ngModelChange`:

```html
<input [ngModel]="user?.name" (ngModelChange)="user.name = $event"/>
```

or as mentioned, you could use `ngIf` and wrap your template in a div like:

```html
<div *ngIf="user">
  <!-- code here-->
</div>
```

or maybe the easiest solution is to just initialize the object. This will work if you do not have nested objects inside your object. So just initialize your user:

```ts
user = {};
```

Comment: only with wrapping the template with `*ngIf` was enought, thanks so much for the help @AJT_82

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the console.log inside the **`subsrcibe`**,

```
public getCurrentUser(): void {
    this.userRef.snapshotChanges().subscribe(action => {
      this.user = action.payload.val();
      console.log(this.user);
    });

  }
```

Comment: yes i know but when i get user object to render on the HTML ionic tell me the user is undefined.

Comment: try with safe navigation operator <img src="{{user?.avatar}}" alt="avatar">

Comment: No it didn´t work. and i have no idea where is the problem.